# Looking for chemicals to melt ice

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, cold-atoms

This might sound like science fiction but I am trying to learn if there is a chemical or material that can convert cold into heat. It also could be kinetic as well. An example would be placing a chemical in cold environment where it becomes warm. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Might [chemistry.se] be better suited for your question?

Comment: You can't convert a lack of energy into energy.
But you can maybe trigger a reaction that would let loose potential energy trapped inside of that matter.

Comment: Wiki page on the [2nd law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics#Clausius_statement)

Comment: "*Looking for chemicals to melt ice*" Salt!

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking for some type of exothermic reaction with the ice.

Salting the ice actually does this (slightly).  It also lowers the freezing temperature of water; which the the main reason it melts the ice.

With enough of a salt you could absolutely heat up ice.  If you wanted to use it to remove snow and ice you might run into other issues; for example it may add heat to the water; but if it's cold outside the water will cool down again once the reaction stops.

Also note that I don't mean only table salt (NaCl); this happens with many different salts; when they disassociate in water they release some energy from the bond (which is the exothermic reaction).

Comment: It seems counterintuitive that releasing energy from an already-frozen material would cause it to melt, but I guess what's actually happening is converting a pure substance below its freezing point to a solution above its freezing point, with an incidental and unrelated decrease in energy.